Why am I getting "FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open 'colorization_deploy_v2.prototxt'" error in OpenCV when loading a Caffe model?
I'm trying to use OpenCV's DNN module to colorize a black-and-white image using a pre-trained Caffe model. However, when I run the following code:
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv2.imwrite('colorized_image.jpg', output)
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe('colorization_deploy_v2.prototxt', 'colorization_release_v2.caffemodel')
image = cv2.imread('bw_image.jpg')
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage

(image, 1.0, (224, 224), (104.00698793, 116.66876762, 122.67891434))
net.setInput(blob)
output = net.forward()[0,:,:,:].transpose((1,2,0))
output = cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_Lab2BGR)

Verifying that the file exists in the correct directory.

Checking file permissions.
Using absolute paths instead of relative paths.

Can anyone help me understand what might be going wrong and how to fix this issue?your text

did you verify that the file exists in the correct directory? how did you verify this? -- open the file with a hex viewer/editor. what's in there? show us

how is the script invoked ? , whats the output of ( dir or ls ) from where you are running the script, if the file really exists and permissions allow it to read by the caller then i'd conclude its not where you think it is or you are not running the script from a location where the file co-exists, i've yet to see an open... fail on a file that is located where it actually is.  does 'colorization_release_v2.caffemodel' exist in the file ? , try opening without this parameter ...

This question is similar to: Can't open prototxt. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
